# hourly to_period 24 hour format ignored

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Sample string:

```
11/8/2017 3:00:00 PM
```

Which is in the dataframe column `sales['Checkin']`

Code for conversion:

```
pd.to_datetime(sales['Checkin'], format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p").dt.to_period('H')
```

This results in:

```
2017-11-08 03:00
```

Thus ignoring the PM... I expected correct result:

```
2017-11-08 15:00
```

I tested it and it seems to be an issue with `to_datetime` and not `to_period`, but I'm not sure what I'm missing because I googled and noticed I am using `%H` correctly, and not `%I` which is the 12 hour format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `%I` rather than `%H`:

```
In [11]: pd.to_datetime(s, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p").dt.to_period('H')
Out[11]:
0   2017-11-08 15:00
dtype: object
```

From the [datetime formatting docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
%H  Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.    
%I  Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
```

Comment: @FredericBastiat ha, I see you mentioned it in your question :) I hadn't even see that, you were so close!

Comment: thank you for the follow up edit, also. I was struggling after changing *both* Hs to Is, which is incorrect